# Errors when trying to install an old version of sf() in R

Tags: r, package, dependencies, r-package

I recently got a new work laptop and am in the midst of re-configuring R to fit a package I use quite frequently (glatos package for telemetry data).

I already downloaded and installed archived versions of rgdal and rgeos (both the 'latest' ones - as they got archived last month) and I re-downloaded/installed RTools.

I got errors saying that 'glatos' needs 'gdalUtilities'. So I tried to download/install that and I got the error saying I need an updated version of 'sf'. (FIRST SET OF ERRORS)

I downloaded the archived version of 'sf' off CRAN (1.0-11) and tried to install it. But then receive the errors below (SECOND SET OF ERRORS). I am really not sure what to make of the sf() errors here and what to do to allow it to successfully install. Could someone please help or give me suggestions?

````
install.packages("gdalUtilities")
also installing the dependencies ‘wk’, ‘s2’, ‘sf’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
              binary source needs_compilation
wk             0.4.1  0.9.0              TRUE
s2             1.0.4  1.1.4              TRUE
sf             0.9-8 1.0-14              TRUE
gdalUtilities  1.1.2  1.2.5             FALSE

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/wk_0.4.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 869220 bytes (848 KB)
downloaded 848 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/s2_1.0.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 5943430 bytes (5.7 MB)
downloaded 5.7 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/sf_0.9-8.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 41978728 bytes (40.0 MB)
downloaded 40.0 MB

package ‘wk’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘s2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘sf’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\WORK\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpsxydIn\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘gdalUtilities’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/gdalUtilities_1.2.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1542252 bytes (1.5 MB)
downloaded 1.5 MB

* installing *source* package 'gdalUtilities' ...
** package 'gdalUtilities' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'sf' 0.9-8 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.11 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'gdalUtilities'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.1/library/gdalUtilities'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gdalUtilities’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\WORK\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpsxydIn\downloaded_packages’```




```install.packages("C:\\Users\\WORK\\Downloads\\sf_1.0-11.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
* installing *source* package 'sf' ...
** package 'sf' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation

   **********************************************
   WARNING: this package has a configure script
         It probably needs manual configuration
   **********************************************


** libs

*** arch - i386
rm -f sf.dll RcppExports.o bbox.o gdal.o gdal_geom.o gdal_read.o gdal_utils.o gdal_write.o geos.o hex.o mdim.o ops.o polygonize.o proj.o proj_info.o raster2sf.o sfc-sfg.o signed_area.o stars.o wkb.o zm_range.o
mkdir -p ../inst
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/bin/i386/Rscript.exe" --vanilla "../tools/winlibs.R" 3.4.1
cp -r "../windows/gdal3-3.4.1/share/gdal" ../inst/
cp -r "../windows/gdal3-3.4.1/share/proj" ../inst/
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I../windows/gdal3-3.4.1/include -DHAVE_PROJ_H -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.1/library/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I../windows/gdal3-3.4.1/include -DHAVE_PROJ_H -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.1/library/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c bbox.cpp -o bbox.o
bbox.cpp:13:3: warning: identifier 'decltype' is a keyword in C++11 [-Wc++0x-compat]
   for (decltype(n) i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   ^
bbox.cpp: In function 'Rcpp::NumericVector CPL_get_bbox(Rcpp::List, int)':
bbox.cpp:9:2: warning: 'auto' changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]
  auto n = sf.size();
  ^
bbox.cpp:9:7: error: 'n' does not name a type
  auto n = sf.size();
       ^
bbox.cpp:13:17: error: 'n' was not declared in this scope
   for (decltype(n) i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                 ^
bbox.cpp:13:18: error: 'decltype' was not declared in this scope
   for (decltype(n) i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                  ^
bbox.cpp:13:27: error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
   for (decltype(n) i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                           ^
bbox.cpp:29:28: error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
    for (decltype(n) i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                            ^
bbox.cpp:31:5: warning: 'auto' changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]
     auto rows = m.nrow();
     ^
bbox.cpp:31:10: error: 'rows' does not name a type
     auto rows = m.nrow();
          ^
bbox.cpp:33:9: error: 'rows' was not declared in this scope
     if (rows > 0) { // non-empty:
         ^
bbox.cpp:39:33: error: 'j' was not declared in this scope
      for (decltype(rows) j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                                 ^
bbox.cpp:51:27: error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
   for (decltype(n) i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                           ^
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf:215: bbox.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'sf'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.1/library/sf'
* restoring previous 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.1/library/sf'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/WORK/Downloads/sf_1.0-11.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status```
````

Comment: You do not say what you chose for the answer to the Q re: binary vs. source although most likely you chose source. Are you really using R 3.6.1? That's pretty old , around 4 years)  and if so, you will need take a lot of care in making versions both of packages and of Rtools compatible based on the dates. Also I have no idea what "CRAN (1.0-11) " means. There's too much missing information about versions to offer well-reasoned advice.